# Quickest way of finding the largest integer n such that n! has length of m bits

Tags: python, python-3.x, time-limit-exceeded

> ## [Factstone Benchmark](https://open.kattis.com/problems/factstone)
>
> Amtel has announced that it will release a 128-bit computer chip by
>   2010, a 256-bit computer by 2020, and so on, continuing its strategy
>   of doubling the word-size every ten years. (Amtel released a 64-bit
>   computer in 2000, a 32-bit computer in 1990, a 16-bit computer in
>   1980, an 8-bit computer in 1970, and a 4-bit computer, its first, in
>   1960.)
>
> Amtel will use a new benchmark – the Factstone – to advertise the
>   vastly improved capacity of its new chips. The Factstone rating is
>   defined to be the largest integer \$n\$ such that \$n!\$ can be represented as an unsigned integer in a computer word.
>
> Given a year \$1960\le y\le 2160\$, what will be the Factstone rating of Amtel's most recently released
>   chip?
>
> ### Input
>
> There are several test cases. For each test case, there is one line of
>   input containing \$y\$. A line containing \$0\$ follows the last test case. >
>
> ### Output
>
> For each test case, output a line giving the Factstone rating.
>
> #### Sample Input 1
>
> ```
> 1960
> 1981
> 0
> ```
>
> #### Sample Output 1
>
> ```
> 3
> 8
> ```

```
import math
n = int(input())
while n != 0:
    n = (n - 1960) / 10 + 2
    m = pow(2,n)
    i = 1
    while m > 0:
        m -= math.log(i,2)
        i += 1
    print(i - 2)
    n = int(input())
```

Can someone please help me time optimize this code? I'm doing it for a site that checks my code but I always fail at the time check.

Comment: You'd get better results by doing a binary search for the answer rather than by searching linearly. Use memoization or some lookup tables to avoid recalculating things that were already calculated.

Answer (score 6):

> ```
> import math
> n = int(input())
> while n != 0:
>     n = (n - 1960) / 10 + 2
> ```

What does `n` represent now? `n` as a name for the value which is called `y` in the task description is already unnecessarily obscure, but aliasing it really confuses things.

In addition, note that in Python `/` does floating point division. If the output for `1969` should be the same as the output for `1960` (and I'm pretty sure the spec requires that) then there's a bug here.

> ```
>     m = pow(2,n)
> ```

What does `m` represent? If you want people to review your code, use descriptive names!

> ```
>     while m > 0:
>         m -= math.log(i,2)
>         i += 1
> ```

How many times does this loop execute for the largest possible input? How can you avoid a linear loop? (Hint: a certain Stirling analysed \$\log n!\$ ...)

(Or, arguably cheating, there are only 21 decades in view, so you could hard-code a lookup.)

Answer (score 2):

You need to use some maths.

You want to know whether

\$n! < 2^b\$  (where \$b\$ is the number of bits)

This is equivalent of:

\$\log n! \lt \log 2^b\$
\$\log n! \lt b\log 2\$

Then we need efficient \$\log n!\$ calculation..

\$\log n!\$ = \$\log (n(n-1)!)\$ = \$\log n + \log (n-1)!\$

We can pre-compute the `log n!` for the first some `n`

The maximum year = 2160, with equals a 4194304 bits computer.

As I'm trying I see you need way to much pre-computed `log n!`, so we need a better way of calculating `log n!`. There exists an solution when `log` is chosen to be the natural logarithm `ln`: 
http://mathworld.wolfram.com/StirlingsApproximation.html

It states:

\$ \ln n! ≈ n \ln n-n+1\$ (for big n)

so we need to solve:

\$ n \ln n-n+1 < b \ln 2\$

For small n we can still use a lookup table. You can determine where the error gets small enough to stop using the lookup-table.

Comment: If \$\log\$ is \$\log_2\$, then you can use \$\log_2n! \lt b\$. Which is really fast and simple.

Comment: Yes, but n! get really bit really fast, so need to find something smarter there yet. Probably log ab = log a + log b ;)

Comment: Do you realise that what you've done here is propose that OP make no changes to his code?

Comment: I believe it is not, as I will never calculate the powers of 2 and get into the big numbers?

Comment: Nor does OP's code. (I agree that `m = pow(2,n)` *looks* like it's doing that, but it turns out to be calculating \$b\$).

Comment: Ah, I see. I stand corrected :)